# DevEcoStudio: DOWNLOAD_SDK_ERROR after upgrading to SDK 6

Tags: sdk, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I have another issue after [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70211512/devecostudio-error-after-upgrading-from-sdk-5-to-sdk6)

**DevEcoStudio Version**: 2.1 Release and 3.0 Beta 1

**SDK:** 6

Already updated `compileSDKVersion` version in project level and module level **build.gradle** files

```
ohos {
    compileSdkVersion 6
    defaultConfig {
        compatibleSdkVersion 5
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardOpt {
                proguardEnabled false
                rulesFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**As the solution in error suggests:**

SdkError: DOWNLOAD_SDK_ERROR
> Cause: Unable to find the toolchains component.
> Solution:
1.Open SDK Manager and download toolchains.
2.Alternatively, modify the compileSdkVersion settings in the project- and module-level build.gradle files.

Navigate to **Tools-> SDK Manager -> Select "SDK Tools" tab under HarmonyOS SDK**. Check "Toolchains" for the installation. Confirm. Accept the agreement and Download.

[image]

Sync and re-build the project successfully.

**EDIT: In case, someone is facing the same issue with the new DevEco IDE (details below) and SDK 6, follow these steps:**

**DevEco Studio Version:**

DevEco Studio 3.0 Beta1
Build Version: 3.0.0.601, built on October 19, 2021

**Solution:**
Open project-level and module-level build.gradle files and change:

```
compileSdkVersion to 6 (by default it is 7)
compatibleSdkVersion to 5 (by default it is 4)
```